# How can I use Java Enums with Amazon DynamoDB and AWS SDK v2?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, enums, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am trying to implement a simple java event-handler lambda for AWS. It receives sqs events and should make appropriate updates to the dynamoDB table.

One of the attributes in this table is a status field that has 4 defined states; therefore I wanted to use an enum class in java and map it to this attribute.

Under AWS SDK v1 I could use the @DynamoDBTypeConvertedEnum annotation. But it does not exist anymore in v2. Instead, there is the @DynamoDbConvertedBy() which receives a converter class reference. There is also an EnumAttributeConverter class which should work nicely with it.

But for some reason, it does not work. The following is a snip from my current code:

```java
@Data
@DynamoDbBean
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Task{

@Getter(onMethod_ = {@DynamoDbPartitionKey})  
    String id; 

...

@Getter(onMethod_ = {@DynamoDbConvertedBy(EnumAttributeConverter.class)})
    ExportTaskStatus status;
}
```

The enum looks as follows:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public enum TaskStatus {
    @JsonProperty("running") PROCESSING(1),
    @JsonProperty("succeeded") COMPLETED(2),
    @JsonProperty("cancelled") CANCELED(3),
    @JsonProperty("failed") FAILED(4);

    private final int order;
}
```

With this, I get the following exception when launching the application:

```
Class 'class software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.internal.converter.attribute.EnumAttributeConverter' appears to have no default constructor thus cannot be used with the BeanTableSchema
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution based on [watkinsmatthewp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69652402/17181638) Answer:

```java
public class TaskStatusConverter implements AttributeConverter<TaskStatus> {
    @Delegate
    private final EnumAttributeConverter<TaskStatus> converter;

    public TaskStatusConverter() {
        converter = EnumAttributeConverter.create(TaskStatus.class);
    }
}
```

Task status attribute looks like this:

```java
@Getter(onMethod_ = {@DynamoDbConvertedBy(TaskStatusConverter.class)})
TaskStatus status;
```

Comment: This answer is outdated. I'm currently using SDK version `2.17.89` and the solution is to just remove the `DynamoDbConvertedBy` annotation.

Answer (score 4):

[How can I use Java Enums with Amazon DynamoDB and AWS SDK v2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69615058/how-can-i-use-java-enums-with-amazon-dynamodb-and-aws-sdk-v2)

Although the [documentation](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/enhanced/dynamodb/mapper/annotations/DynamoDbConvertedBy.html) doesn't state it, the `DynamoDbConvertedBy` annotation requires any [`AttriuteConverter`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/enhanced/dynamodb/AttributeConverter.html) you supply to contain a parameterles default constructor

Unfortunately for you and me, whoever wrote many of the built-in `AttributeConverter` classes decided to use static `create()` methods to instantiate them instead of a constructor (maybe they're singletons under the covers? I don't know). This means anyone who wants to use these helpful constructor-less classes like [`InstantAsStringAttributeConverter`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/enhanced/dynamodb/internal/converter/attribute/InstantAsStringAttributeConverter.html) and [`EnumAttributeConverter`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/enhanced/dynamodb/internal/converter/attribute/EnumAttributeConverter.html) needs to wrap them in custom wrapper classes that simple parrot the converters we instantiated using `create`. For a non-generic typed class like `InstantAsStringAttributeConverter`, this is easy. Just create an wrapper class that parrots the instance you new up with `create()` and refer to that instead:

```java
public class InstantAsStringAttributeConverterWithConstructor implements AttributeConverter<Instant> {
    private final static InstantAsStringAttributeConverter CONVERTER = InstantAsStringAttributeConverter.create();

    @Override
    public AttributeValue transformFrom(Instant instant) {
        return CONVERTER.transformFrom(instant);
    }

    @Override
    public Instant transformTo(AttributeValue attributeValue) {
        return CONVERTER.transformTo(attributeValue);
    }

    @Override
    public EnhancedType<Instant> type() {
        return CONVERTER.type();
    }

    @Override
    public AttributeValueType attributeValueType() {
        return CONVERTER.attributeValueType();
    }
}
```

Then you update your annotation to point to that class intead of the actual underlying library class.

But wait, `EnumAttributeConverter` is a generic typed class, which means you need to go one step further. First, you need to create a version of the converter that wraps the official version but relies on a constructor taking in the type instead of static instantiation:

```java
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.AttributeConverter;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.AttributeValueType;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.EnhancedType;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.internal.converter.attribute.EnumAttributeConverter;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.AttributeValue;

public class EnumAttributeConverterWithConstructor<T extends Enum<T>> implements AttributeConverter<T> {
    private final EnumAttributeConverter<T> converter;

    public CustomEnumAttributeConverter(final Class<T> enumClass) {
        this.converter = EnumAttributeConverter.create(enumClass);
    }

    @Override
    public AttributeValue transformFrom(T t) {
        return this.converter.transformFrom(t);
    }

    @Override
    public T transformTo(AttributeValue attributeValue) {
        return this.converter.transformTo(attributeValue);
    }

    @Override
    public EnhancedType<T> type() {
        return this.converter.type();
    }

    @Override
    public AttributeValueType attributeValueType() {
        return this.converter.attributeValueType();
    }
}
```

But that only gets us half-way there-- now we need to generate a version for each enum type we want to convert that subclasses our custom class:

```java
public class ExportTaskStatusAttributeConverter extends EnumAttributeConverterWithConstructor<ExportTaskStatus> {
    public ExportTaskStatusAttributeConverter() {
        super(ExportTaskStatus.class);
    }
}
```

```java
@DynamoDbConvertedBy(ExportTaskStatusAttributeConverter.class)
public ExportTaskStatus getStatus() { return this.status; }
```

Or the Lombok-y way:

```java
@Getter(onMethod_ = {@DynamoDbConvertedBy(ExportTaskStatusAttributeConverter.class)})
ExportTaskStatus status;
```

It's a pain. It's a pain that could be solved with a little bit of tweaking and a tiny bit of reflection in the AWS SDK, but it's where we're at right now.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else coming here, it looks to me like just dropping the annotation from the enum altogether works just fine, i.e. the SDK applies the provided attribute converters implicitly. This is also mentioned in this [Github issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/2335#issuecomment-811273037). My own class looks like this (Brand is an enum here), and the enum is converted without any issues when fetching items.

```
@Value
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@DynamoDbImmutable(builder = User.UserBuilder.class)
public class User {

    @Getter(onMethod = @__({@DynamoDbPartitionKey}))
    String id;

    Brand brand;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The dynamodb-enhanced SDK does this out of the box.

When you declare a `@DynamoDbBean` the `DefaultAttributeConverterProvider` provides a long list of possible ways to convert attributes between java types, including an `EnumAttributeConverter` which is used if `type.rawClass().isEnum()` is true. So you don't need to worry about it.

If you ever wanted to extend the number of converters, you would need to add the `converterProviders` annotation parameter, and declare the default one (or omit it), as well as any other providers you want.

Example:
`@DynamoDbBean(converterProviders = { DefaultAttributeConverterProvider.class, MyCustomAttributeConverterProvider.class });`

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking that your annotations might actually be the problem here. I would remove all annotations that mention a constructor, and instead, write out your own constructor(s). For both `Task` and `TaskStatus`.